# New to IOS dev center, how do I use my own phone to run apps?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have only used Xcode by its self and I just paid and registered for my IOS development license. I really need to use my own phone to run my apps but when I tried I just got this Error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'tanner.appname' could not be found. I don't know what a provisions file is or anything else. Can someone please help?

Comment: everything you'll need can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome dev!

Here is an quick tutorial for your provision error: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone

Or you can use the launch assistent.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register at the [apple development center](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).  You will need to register the device and download the correct provisioning profile.

Also, open the Xcode organizer (Window -> Organizer) and make sure your phone is plugged in and then mark it as "Use this device for development".

Lastly, apple documentation on the provisioning and development center can be found here: [Provisioning And Development](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)